# (g)vim - NerdTree and tagbar above each other left to edited file?

Tags: vim, vimrc, gvim

Any chance to get (g)vim displaying [NerdTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) and [tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) above each other left to edited file?

```
+-----------+-------------+
| nerd tree | edited file |
| contents  |             |
+-----------+             |
| tagbar    |             |
| contents  |             |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I'd like to have it done in `.vimrc` somehow.

Up to now the relevant section in my `.vimrc` looks like this:

```
" NERDTree shortcut
:nmap \e :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
" tagbar settings
let g:tagbar_left=1
nnoremap <silent> <F9> :TagbarToggle<CR>
```

However when displayed, they're shown like this:

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+
| tagbar   | nerd tree | edited file |
| contents | contents  |             |
|          |           |             |
|          |           |             |
|          |           |             |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be difficult. Both `:NERDTreeToggle` and `:TagbarToggle` use `:vsplit` internally, and there's no way to simply reconfigure or hook into it.

You'd have to write wrappers for your `\e` and `<F9>` triggers that detect the current window layout, do the toggling, and then jiggle the windows around to fit your requirements. That last step alone is already quite involved. You have to push one of the sidebar windows down with `:wincmd J`, then make the right file window full-height again win `:wincmd L`.

You see, it's not easy. What I do instead is always have only one of those plugins active. My personal mappings check for open sidebars, and close e.g. Tagbar before toggling on NERD_tree. That's much easier to implement.

Comment: thanks for answer, I'll try to check what I can achieve for my usecase here

Comment: I'd love a link to your function for making them globally unique … especially if it works with [`jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs`](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs). <3

Answer (score 3):

I took a vim function written by Jan Larres in the question "
How to open or close NERDTree and Tagbar with < leader>\?" 
and modified it (I only added the wincmd commands)to make my vim look like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+ 
| Tagbar    |    file     |
| contents  |             |
+-----------+             |
| NERDTree  |             | 
| contents  |             |
+-----------+-------------+
```

function! ToggleNERDTreeAndTagbar()
    let w:jumpbacktohere = 1

```
" Detect which plugins are open
if exists('t:NERDTreeBufName')
    let nerdtree_open = bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1
else
    let nerdtree_open = 0
endif
let tagbar_open = bufwinnr('__Tagbar__') != -1

" Perform the appropriate action
if nerdtree_open && tagbar_open
    NERDTreeClose
    TagbarClose
elseif nerdtree_open
    TagbarOpen
    wincmd J
    wincmd k
    wincmd L
elseif tagbar_open
    NERDTree
    wincmd J
    wincmd k
    wincmd L
else
    NERDTree
    TagbarOpen
    wincmd J
    wincmd k
    wincmd L
endif

" Jump back to the original window
for window in range(1, winnr('$'))
    execute window . 'wincmd w'
    if exists('w:jumpbacktohere')
        unlet w:jumpbacktohere
        break
    endif
endfor  
 endfunction
 nnoremap <leader>\ :call ToggleNERDTreeAndTagbar()<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Any way to preserve the default widths?